# How can I make my where statement work here?

Tags: mysql

I have this update query and it works when my where has 2 conditions but when I added 3 more it doesn't work. Can anyone look at it and tell me whats wrong. Thank you.

Heres my query:

```
$sSQLupdate = "UPDATE settings, holidaytype SET 
settings.companyName = '$companyname', 
settings.companyAddress = '$companyaddress', 
settings.companyContact = '$companycontact', 
settings.excessot1 = '$excessot1', 
settings.multiplierOT1 = '$multiplier1', 
settings.excessot2 = '$excessot2', 
settings.multiplierOT2 = '$multiplier2', 
settings.ndRangeFrom = '$ND_in',
settings.ndRangeTo = '$ND_out',
settings.multiplierNd = '$NDmul',
holidaytype.multiplier = '$regularmul',      *(mustbe in holidaytype.id = '1')
holidaytype.multiplier = '$specialmul',      *(mustbe in holidaytype.id = '2')
holidaytype.multiplier = '$doubleregmulmul', *(mustbe in holidaytype.id = '3')
holidaytype.multiplier = '$doublespecmul'    *(mustbe in holidaytype.id = '4')

WHERE settings.id = 1 AND holidaytype.id = '1' AND holidaytype.id = '2' AND holidaytype.id = '3' AND holidaytype.id = '4'";
```

Comment: how can the `holidaytype.id` be 1 AND 2 AND 3 AND 4 at the same time?

Comment: What is the `*(mustbe in ...)` stuff? That doesn't look like valid SQL syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE settings.id = 1 AND holidaytype.id IN ('1','2','3','4')
```

To update the `holidaytype.multiplier` by condition depending on `holidaytype.id` I suggest to use `CASE` statement or seperate queries.

Answer (score 1):

Because all the three conditions cannot be true simulataneouly ie,

```
WHERE settings.id = 1 AND holidaytype.id = '1' AND holidaytype.id = '2' AND holidaytype.id = '3' AND holidaytype.id = '4'";
```

if `holidaytype.id = '1'` then it cannot be `'2' or '3' or '4'`

You better need to use **IN**

```
WHERE settings.id = 1 AND holidaytype.id IN ('1','2','3','4')
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use `OR` instead of `AND` `AND` because they cant be true all at the same time , one of them must be true. try this:

```
   WHERE settings.id = 1 
   AND (holidaytype.id = '1' OR holidaytype.id ='2' OR holidaytype.id ='3' OR holidaytype.id ='4')";
```

or use this with `IN` clause:

```
   WHERE settings.id = 1 AND holidaytype.id IN ('1','2','3','4')";
```

---

Your Update have no meaning , update two tables with conditions of eachother. either update each table alone or use join the tables.

Comment: Use `IN` instead of lots of `OR`s

Comment: @Barmar i knew believe me i was writing it before you comment :)

Comment: You miss the last `)` in statement, if OP copy-paste your answer it will not work

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis to separate boolean statements:

```
WHERE settings.id = 1 AND (holidaytype.id = '1' OR holidaytype.id = '2' OR holidaytype.id = '3' OR holidaytype.id = '4');
```